Can I include ideas from a referee report from a paper with a coauthor without involving the coauthor in the next project?
I am a young researcher. In the past, I have collaborated with someone a few times whose contribution was very minimal, and their claim to coauthorship is questionable (yet I let them have it). Awhile back, after communicating to them my concerns, I cut my ties and have not worked with them since.
Recently, with this collaborator, we had a paper recently rejected from a journal. However, in one my new collaborations with other researchers, I realized a way to leverage some of the ideas in the referee report to upgrade the new project. This makes the older collaboration a bit obsolete, and I would prefer to avoid merging projects for the mentioned reasons.
I have no idea how to proceed forward. Any suggestions?

"We had a paper recently rejected from a journal" Who is "we"? Does this include the collaborator you dislike?

I have edited the post! Thanks for pointing this out!

Okay, thanks. So your question is basically, "Can I include ideas from a referee report from a paper with author X without involving them in the next project?"

Yes! I want to be 'ethical' in every capacity with things like including ideas from a referee report on a separate project, but also not including them to keep distance.

Okay, thanks. By "obsolete," do you mean "I am no longer interested in publishing the paper [that was just rejected]?"

If you are able to publish the existing work with your coauthor, I think that ends your responsibility to them neatly. Most work comes out of past work of your own in some way, you don't need to continue including all past collaborators with each new work. The way to credit those past collaborators is through citation.
It gets a bit dodgy if you plan not to publish that work anymore, especially if the new project will then overlap with something unpublished. A middle ground option might be to at least have it released as a preprint with your original planned author list. Then, in the new work you can use citation of that preprint to credit their contributions, just as if the work was published in a journal.
However, I think if that's your plan it's still worth a conversation with all your coauthors to discuss planning to post as a preprint and then leave it there and not pursue publication further. If coauthors disagree, then they need to be willing to put whatever effort in that would make that paper publishable. I'm guessing they won't really want to do this.

This was very helpful, I appreciate it! I will surely try the first option before deciding to not publish.
